# Unit Testing in C#

Tags: c#

Junior Web Developer and I have been tasked with creating Unit Test for a project.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: your test should not be dependent from user. You should do some mocking.

Comment: Change testing framework to NUnit which supports test cases. Then make different cases for "test.user", "Test.User", "TEST.USER" etc, and validate using StringAssert class which allows you to check string equivalence independent of casing.

Comment: What does the framework has to do with this? What he wants to do is perfectly possible with MS-test

Comment: I'm sure the developers for this project would be too happy if the OP completely changed the test framework just because it might make writing this single test case slightly easier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGetUser()//Shell Complete, test code needs review
{
    try
    {
        //set test to get user 
        AsaMembershipProvider prov = this.GetMembershipProvider();
        //call get user
        MembershipUser user = prov.GetUser("test.user", false);



        //ask for the username with deliberate case differences
         MembershipUser user2 = prov.GetUser("TeSt.UsEr", false);


        //prove that you still get the user,
        Assert.AreNotEqual(null, user);
        Assert.AreNotEqual(null, user2);

        //test by using the “.ToLower()” function on the resulting string.
        //verify case doesn’t matter on username.
        Assert.AreEqual(user.UserName.ToLower(), user2.UserName.ToLower());
        Assert.AreEqual(user.UserName.ToLower(), "test.user");
     }
catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogMessage(ex);
        Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far, as I understand, you are asking to check whether your code meets requirements?
I do not know about your user and user providers, but you also need to

Change

```
Assert.AreEqual(user.UserName, "test.user");
```

to

```
Assert.AreEqual("test.user", user.UserName.ToLower()); //EXPECTED, then ACTUAL
```

or even more correct way to do this:

```
StringAssert.AreEqualIgnoringCase("test.user", user.UserName);
```

This change will satisfy your original requirement:

```
//test by using the “.ToLower()” function on the resulting string.
//verify case doesn’t matter on username.
```

More on [AreEqual](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=comparisonAsserts&r=2.2)

More on [StringAssert](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=stringAssert&r=2.6.1)